# Uniswap "getAmountOut" function

Tags: uniswap

I would like to get a price of a pair on Uniswap using the router contract for Uniswap:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d#readContract

The problem is when I use the "getAmountOut" function on etherscan, it outputs an amount that doesn't represent the price I would expect. For example, the WETH / DAI pair outputs an amount like '1100000' instead of the price closer to 1300 like I would expect (current ETH/Dai price). Is there some kind of conversion that I need to do to get an accurate price using that function?